# "The option setting 'android.experimental.testOptions.emulatorSnapshots.maxSnapshotsForTestFailures=0' is experimental" ERROR

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

I have encountered this problem in my androidstudio application.I've checked my build.gradle and I don't have the maxSnapshotsForTestFailures added.I've searched the entire application and I haven't added what the compiler says I have.

Answer (score 0):

Please check into your `build.gradle` file, probably you are using `moduleData.id` instead of `moduleData.getGradlePath()`.

in fact there is an issue reported to Google:

[Instrumented tests fail with "Project 'X' not found in root project 'X'."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219164389)

```
    private fun getTaskNames(androidModuleModel: GradleAndroidModel): List<String> {
        return listOf(
          //"${moduleData.id}:connected${androidModuleModel.selectedVariantName.usLocaleCapitalize()}AndroidTest"
"${moduleData.getGradlePath()}:connected${androidModuleModel.selectedVariantName.usLocaleCapita
lize()}AndroidTest"
        )
      }
```